# Can't load Image one time using getGraphics() method

Tags: java, image, swing

Hi I'm new to java GUI Programming. I created `Jframe(MainFrame)` and add `JPanel(OutPanel)` Which has another `Jpanel(InnerPanel)`. I try to achieve drawing Image in `InnerPanel`, not drawing `OutPanel`. I want `OutPanel` used to be just `Container`. So as you see TestA. I get `Graphics` from `InnerPanel` in `OutPanel`'s `paintComponent()` which is overided method.

So finally I can draw using `InnerPanel`'s `Graphics` in `OutPanel`'s `paintComponent()` method. but It couldn't work well. It couldn't draw Image one time when program starts. when I hided window and shown again, the program shows image. Even though that is part of Image, not all Image.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestA{

    private static Image image = GUI.loadImage("PlayerBoard.jpg");


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestA testA = new TestA();
    }


    public TestA() {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainFrame.setLocation(800, 400);

        OutPanel outPanel = new OutPanel();

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(outPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        outPanel.repaint();
    }

    private class OutPanel extends JPanel {

        JPanel innerPanel;

        public OutPanel() {

            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setLocation(0, 0);
            this.setSize(500, 50);
            this.setBackground(Color.red);

            innerPanel = new JPanel();
            this.innerPanel.setSize(400, 50);
            this.innerPanel.setVisible(true);
            this.add(innerPanel);

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = 500;
            int height = 50;

            BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
            Graphics gBuffer = resized.createGraphics();
            gBuffer.drawImage(TestA.image, 0, 0, width, height, this);

            Graphics gPanel = innerPanel.getGraphics();
            gPanel.drawImage(resized, 0, 0, width, height, this);
        }
    }
}
```

So I try diffrerent way(TestB). Only different thing is I just moved `drawImage()` method and `getGraphics()` thing to `InnerPanel`'s `paintComponent()` from `OutPanel`'s `paintComponent()`. Here's another Code TestB. and It works well.

Why this happens. Is it relates to `context`?. What is `Context`. and could I draw `InnerPanel's` Image in `OutPanel`?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestB {

    private static Image image = GUI.loadImage("PlayerBoard.jpg");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestB testB = new TestB();
    }

    public TestB() {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainFrame.setLocation(800, 400);

        OutPanel outPanel = new OutPanel();

        mainFrame.add(outPanel);

        outPanel.repaint();

    }

    private class OutPanel extends JPanel {

        JPanel innerPanel;

        public OutPanel() {

            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setLocation(0, 0);
            this.setSize(500, 50);
            this.setBackground(Color.red);

            innerPanel = new InnerPanel(this);
            this.innerPanel.setSize(500, 50);
            this.innerPanel.setVisible(true);
            this.add(innerPanel);

            this.repaint();
        }
    }

    private class InnerPanel extends JPanel {

        OutPanel outPanel;

        public InnerPanel(OutPanel outPanel) {
            this.outPanel = outPanel;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = 500;
            int height = 50;

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.drawImage(TestB.image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static Image image = GUI.loadImage("PlayerBoard.jpg");` Where is the code for `GUI`? In any case, given the `static` I can only guess it is trying to load the image by `File`, and on that.. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 2):

The paintComponent() method of a component is responsible for painting itself only. It should never know or care about any other component.

> I want OutPanel used to be just Container.

Then do just that. Create the panel and set the layout manager for the outer panel and then add the outer panel to the JFrame.

Then create your inner panel and add it to the outer panel. Make sure you override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the inner panel so the layout manager of the outer panel can do its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, You mean outer component does not know even if it is one of added components?

Comment: @DoyoonKim, The outer component doesn't care. Swing will automatically paint the component and all its child components. The painting code should only ever worry about painting itself, not any child (or parent) component.